# How can I get DD-MM-YY hh:mm a, en-US, +0100 format using new Date()

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, time

I want time and date format like this

`UK: 08-08-21 01:27 PM`

`SL: 08-08-21 05:57 PM`

I tried with this. But i does not work properly

```
this.subscription = timer(0, 60000)
      .pipe(
        map(() => new Date()),
        share()
      )
      .subscribe(time => {

        let day = new Date().getDay();
        let month = new Date().getMonth();
        let year = new Date().getFullYear();
        let SlHour = new Date().getHours();
        let UkHour = new Date().getUTCHours()+ 1;
        let minuts = new Date().getUTCMinutes();

        let SLTime = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + UkHour + ":" + minuts
        let UKTime = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + SlHour + ":" + minuts
     }
```

Can anyone help me to get like this format

UK: **08-08-21 01:27 PM**

SL: **08-08-21 05:57 PM**

Comment: Please define *"does not work properly"* in more specific technical terms. In other words.... What is or isn't working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to format the date seperator `-`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    UK:
    <h4 id="app-uk"></h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    SL:
    <h4 id="app-sl"></h4>
  </div>

  <script>
    let now = new Date();

    let formatDateUK = now.toLocaleString("en-UK", {
      dateStyle: "short",
      timeStyle: "short",
      hour12: true
    });

    let formatDateSL = now.toLocaleString("en-SL", {
      dateStyle: "short",
      timeStyle: "short",
      hour12: true
    });

    let displayDateUK = document.querySelector("#app-uk");
    displayDateUK.innerHTML = formatDateUK;

    let displayDateSL = document.querySelector("#app-sl");
    displayDateSL.innerHTML = formatDateSL;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For UK in Safari I get 8/9/21, 6:51 AM which might be unexpected given it's 9 August.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a `formatDate` function. If `ukTime` is true, the result will be London time, and if it is false you will get local time. This should work for your purpose.

The UK time is generated using a date-string-date method because adding 1 to the hour can result in invalid times.

Edit: Fixed 00AM to 12AM.

```js
function formatDate(ukTime = false) {
    let dt;
    if (ukTime) dt = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/London" }));
    else dt = new Date();

    let dayStr = dt.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0"),
        monthStr = (dt.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0"),
        yearStr = dt.getYear().toString().substring(1, 3);
    let hour = dt.getHours() > 12 ? dt.getHours() - 12 : (dt.getHours() == 0 ? 12 : dt.getHours());
    
    return `${dayStr}-${monthStr}-${yearStr} ${hour.toString().padStart(2, "0")}:${dt.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0")} ${dt.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"}`;
}


console.log(formatDate(true))
console.log(formatDate(false))
```

Comment: Thank you. But i want time should update every minutes .

Comment: If you want to update, make a function that runs often and updates the time using formatDate.

Comment: Consider `let hour = dt.getHours() % 12 || 12`.

Comment: The strategy of creating a string then parsing it to create a timezone–shifted date as in `dt = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/London" }));` is flawed as it relies on the built–in parser parsing the output of *toLocaleSring* when it's not required to do so (and won't in many cases) and it may generate a time that either doesn't exist locally or exists twice during DST transitions. Better to use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) with an appropriate IANA location.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, that’d probably work better.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of errors in the code:

```
let day = new Date().getDay();
```

returns the day number (Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, etc.) not the date

```
let month = new Date().getMonth();
```

returns the month index where Jan = 0, Feb = 1, etc. so you need to add 1 to get the calendar month number.

```
let UkHour = new Date().getUTCHours()+ 1;
```

This assumes that the UK time is always UTC +1, which it isn't and also will return 24 when the hour should be 0.

The code also creates a new Date object each time, which is inefficient. To get the date and time in a particular location, use the *timeZone* option of the [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), which is also available through [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Since localised formats of dates and times are not standardised, you might use the *formatToParts* method that returns the parts of a date as an array of objects, where each part has a name and value. Then you can reliably format the parts, e.g. assuming "SL" means "standard local":

```js
// Format date as DD/MM/YY h:mm AP
function formatDate(date = new Date(), location) {
  // Standard options
  let opts = {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: '2-digit',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
  };
  // Add timezone if supplied
  if (location) {
    opts.timeZone = location;
  }
  // Create a formatter  
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', opts);
  // Get the parts
  let {year, month, day, hour, minute, dayPeriod} = f.formatToParts(date).reduce(
    (acc, part) => {
      acc[part.type] = part.value;
      return acc
    }, {}
  );
  // Return formatted string
  return `${day}-${month}-${year} ${hour}:${minute} ${dayPeriod.toUpperCase()}`;
}

console.log('UK (London): ' + formatDate(new Date(), 'Europe/London'));
console.log('Vladivostok: ' + formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Vladivostok'))
console.log('Local      : ' + formatDate());
```

The format DD-MM-YY is ambiguous, not least due to the US penchant for M/D/Y but also because many places use Y-M-D, so 01-02-03 might be interpreted 3 different ways. Better to use the short month name to avoid that, e.g. 09-Aug-21. Four digit year would also be better.